# What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $(a+1)^{7^n} = (a+1)$?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

In $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_7[X]/(X^2+1)$ let $a$ be the class of $X$. What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $(a+1)^{7^n} = (a+1)$ ?

I know that the answer is $2$ but I don't see how it works. Can someone explain the logic to me? Because if I get it correctly, $a = X$ in this case and we're reducing $mod$ $X^2 +1$ so how does $ a^{49} +1$ equal to $a+1$ ?

Comment: Hint: What is $a^4$?

Comment: $n=2$ is incorrect.

Comment: May be it should read $(a+1)^{7^n}=(a+1)$? That way $n=2$ comes out the right answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, my bad. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is in characteristic $7$, $(x+1)^7 = x^7 + 1$ for any $x$, and
$(a+1)^{49} = (a^7+1)^7 = a^{49} + 1$.  Since $a^2 = -1$, $a^{48} = 1$ so 
$a^{49} + 1 = a + 1$.

Comment: Why is $a^2 = -1$ ?

Comment: Why is $n=7$ the smallest one?

Comment: because we are working with $\mod a^{2} +1$, so we know $a^{2}+1=0 \Leftrightarrow a^{2} = -1$

Comment: It seems you have misread the problem: the exponent is $\,\large 7n\,$ not $\,\large 7^{\Large n}\,\ $  @AbdulMalekAltawekji Which exponent is actually intended?

Comment: @BillDubuque My bad, I fixed it now. I indeed meant $7^n$

Comment: @Abdul Ok, now you have answers for the easy $7^{\large n}$ case *and* the more general $7n$ case.

Answer (score 1):

[Note: this answer applies to the original more general question with exponent $7n$ vs. $7^{\large n}$]

$ \mathbb{F}_{\large 7}[x]/(x^2\!+\!1)\cong \Bbb F_{\large 7}[\,i\,]\,$ where $\,\overline{a\!+\!bi} = (a\!+\!bi)^{\large 7}\! = a\!-\!bi\,$ is the  conjugation automorphism.

If $\,w = 1\!+\!i\,$ then $\,(1\!+\!w)^{\large 7n}\! = 1\!+\!i \!\iff\! \bar w^{\large n} = w.\,$  Taking norm $\,N(x) = x\bar x\, $ of both sides yields $2^{\large n}\! = 2\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_{\large 7}\!\!\iff n\equiv 1\!\pmod{\!3},\,$ by $\,2\,$ has order $3$. $\,n = 7\,$ works: $\ \bar w^7\! = \bar {\bar w} = w,\, $ but no smaller $n$ works: $\,\bar w\neq w\,$ so $\,n\neq 1,\,$ and $\,n \neq  4\,$ else $\, \bar w^4\! = w = \bar w^7\Rightarrow\, 1 = \bar w^3 \Rightarrow\, \bar w = \bar w^4\! = w$.

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

The question can be rephrased as

> What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $(a+1)^{7n-1} = 1$?

Let $m$ be the order of $a+1$ in the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}^\times$, which has order $48$.

Then $m$ divides $\gcd(7n-1,48)$. Let's see the possibilities:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrr}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
7n-1 & 6 & 13 & 20 & 27 & 34 & 41 & 48 \\
\gcd(7n-1,48) & 6 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 48
\end{array}
$$
By checking that $(a+1)^k \ne 1$ for $k=1,2,3,4,6$, we arrive at $n=7$.

Comment: Taking norms leaves $\,n = 4\,$ as the only nontrivial case to exclude - see my answer.